# new TNS Entry not working in visual studio/attunity

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, attunity

Im using visual studio 2013 & the attunity connector to connect to oracle and extract data. As its visual studio, i have the 32 bit oracle drivers installed.

Note both connections work when testing via a 32 bit & 64 bit  UDL.

For the first TNS Entry (below), the connection works, both in visual studioL. 
For the other i get an error in visual studio:

```
ORA-12154: tns:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

As the drivers are clearly working when trying via UDL, I dont want to change too much, but need to get both TNS Entries working.

Is there an issue with the 2nd TNS Entry that Attunity may not be able to handle it?

```
conn1 = (DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = xxx.xxx.xxx.45)(PORT = 1543)))
      (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = conn1)))

conn2 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = xxx.xxx.xxx.54)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = conn2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubleshooting and pulling out of hair, we figured out that if we simply recreate the attunity oracle connection in Visual Studio, it works.

It seems to be an attunity connector problem, and may even be resolved in a later version of the connector ( we are using a version from 15 months ago).

This might help someone save a few hours troubleshooting in future.